# One-to-one in sequelize-typescript with multiple foreign keys

Tags: typescript, database, sequelize.js, foreign-keys, sequelize-typescript

My question is, how can I add multiple foreign keys to an object. I have an example with Complaint. And contains 2 Transports. One to track the goods being sent back and one to track the goods being sent again to the customer.

```
@Table({ tableName: "transport" })
export class Transport extends Model {

    @Column
    trackingNumber?: string;
}


export class Complaint extends Model {

    @ForeignKey(() => Transport)
    returnGoodsTransportId!: bigint;

    @BelongsTo(() => Transport)
    returnGoodsTransport!: Transport;

    @ForeignKey(() => Transport)
    resendGoodsTransportId!: bigint;

    @BelongsTo(() => Transport)
    resendGoodsTransport!: Transport;
}
```

For this purposes I removed my unnecessary code from the model.

With this example I only end up with only one Foreign key in the database. The first one in the Complaint.

I am expecting both foreign keys in the db table

Comment: To define multiple foreign keys in a Sequelize model, you can simply define multiple properties with the `@ForeignKey` decorator and the corresponding `@BelongsTo` decorator. It looks like you have already done this in your Complaint model, so the foreign keys should be correctly defined.

Comment: @MrSolarius thanks for the answer. The bad thing is after running the code there is only 1 foreign key in the mysql db not 2 FK..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in case anybody faces this problem.

I found the answer here:
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript/issues/266

I had to link my "belongTo" to my FK, because otherwise belongTo didnt know which FK to take so it took the first one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).